# How can I print out the elements of my Stack class in C++ using std::vector and std::cout?

Tags: c++, stack, stdvector

I need to print out elements of my `Stack` class, but I have no idea how to do so.

I'm currently working on the Tower of Hanoi problem, and to do so I have created a `Stack` class, which is basically a vector of cubes (created also the `Cube` class, which is inheriting a `Shape` class):

**Stack.h**

```
#pragma once
#include <vector>
#include "Cube.h"
#include <ostream>

namespace uiuc{
    class Stack{
        private:
            std::vector<Cube> stackOfCubes;
            int size_;
        public:
            Cube& pop();//gets the last cube of the stack and removes it
            void push(Cube cube);//pushes a cube into the stack 
            void peek();//prints out ALL the stack
            int size();
        friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const Stack& stack){
            return stack.stackOfCubes;
        };
    };
}
```

I want to work on the `peek()` method, which prints out ALL the stack of cubes, but nonetheless I have no idea how to do so since `std::cout` doesn't know how to print out class objects.

I have found on other questions that I should overload `operator<<`, but it says the following error when I try to return the `stackOfCubes`:

> a reference of type "std::ostream &" (not const-qualified) cannot be initialized with a value of type "const std::vector<uiuc::Cube, std::allocator<uiuc::Cube>>

Comment: Any concise reasons why you're not simply using  `std::stack`?

Comment: _"std::cout doesn't know how to print out class objects"_ - so add `std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream&, const Cube&)`?

Comment: i thought it would be a good idea to learn building it from scratch since i only started learning about c++

Comment: *i thought it would be a good idea to learn building it from scratch* -- If you were developing a game, would you want to build the game engine from scratch?  The goal of your program is Towers of Hanoi -- if you use a `std::stack` doesn't mean the program will write itself automatically -- you still have to write the code to complete the Towers of Hanoi program.  What using `std::stack` *will* do is to allow you to use a bugless class that helps you complete your goal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message is telling you that you can't initialize a `std::ostream&` reference with a `const std::vector<Cube>` object, which is what your `return stack.stackOfCubes;` statement is trying to do.

Your `operator<<` should not `return` the stack at all, it needs to `return` the provided `ostream` instead.  Your `operator<<` should write the contents of the stack to that stream, eg:

```
friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const Stack& stack){
    // iterate stack.stackOfCubes, writing each Cube to os as needed...
    return os;
};
```

For example:

```
class Cube : public Shape {
    ...
    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const Cube& cube){
        // write cube members to os as needed...
        return os;
    }
};

class Stack {
    ...
    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const Stack& stack){
        for(const Cube &cube : stack.stackOfCubes) {
            os << cube;
        }
        return os;
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide an overload for `operator<<` that accepts a `Cube` and writes it to the output stream. The signature would be something like,

```cpp
std::ostream& operator<<(std::stream& os, const Cube& cube);
```

And, then, you can implement your stack output with a simple loop,

```cpp
friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const Stack& stack) {
    os << "{ ";
    for (const auto& elem : stack.stackOfCubes)
        os << elem << " ";
    os << "}";
    return os;
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much!! i kind of understand the gist of it now !